# How to change Mui DataGrid toolbar color?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Here's my custom Toolbar for Mui dataGrid

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )
}
```

How do I change the color?
The default color is this:
[image]

Comment: The color of the buttons is associated with the palette theme. Here is what you should change in the custom theme palette to achieve the results.
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color of the CustomToolBar by adding the following CSS code to the GridToolBarContainer:

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton style={{ color: '#3f51b5' }} />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton style={{ color: '#3f51b5' }} />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector style={{ color: '#3f51b5' }} />
      <GridToolbarExport style={{ color: '#3f51b5' }} />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )
}
```

If you want to use a Hex color code, Replace "blue" with the desired hex color code, including the "#" symbol.

Comment: This changes the background color of the toolbar and not the button text colors.

Comment: In this case, you must first determine the CSS classes associated with each button before applying your custom styles to those classes. I modified the code to meet your requirements.

Comment: ah, I was trying  <GridToolbarColumnsButton style={{ color: "primary"}}/>
and it wasn't working. 
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `color` prop and use your theme styling

`<GridToolbarColumnsButton color="secondary" />`
There's no need to add manual styling.